# Change in the class of progressive bar depending on the width

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on progressive bar. The thing I am doing here is if the percentage crosses 50% then the background color should be `bg-success` or else the background should be `bg-danger`.

I came across many answers but none worked for me please any assistance would really help me in getting this worked. Below is the code what I have tried with.

```html
<td>
  <span class="header-text">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active progressbartextcolor" 
      id="progressbarcolorbelow50percent" role="progressbar" 
      v-bind:style="{width: customerLoan.progress + '%'}">
      {{customerLoan.progress || "0"}}%
    </div>
  </span>
</td>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var barcolor = $('.progress-bar');
    var percent = 100 * (barcolor.width() / $('#progressbarcolorbelow50percent').width());
    if (percent <= 50) {
      barcolor.addClass('bg-danger');
    }
    else {
      barcolor.addClass('bg-success');
    }
  });
</script>
```